Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass error
I get a "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass" error while trying to send email using outlook in Windows application.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook dll is not supporting MS outlook 2021

Please advise is there any alternative. Thank you.
Error message:

Unable to cast COM object of type ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass’ to interface type ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application’.

Sample code:
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

public Boolean SendEmailThroughOUTLOOK()
{
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();            
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);            
                 
    try
    {
            if (Directory.GetFiles(WIPFolder).Length != 0)
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(WIPFolder);                   
                String sDisplayName = "FeedbackForm";
                int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
                int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;

                // now attach the file
                foreach (string SourceFile in files)
                {
                    Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(SourceFile, iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
                }                   

                oRecip.Resolve();              
                oMsg.Send();      // Here I am getting the error

                return true;                 
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        oRecip = null;
        oRecips = null;
        oMsg = null;
        oApp = null;
    }

    return false;
}

Looking for alternative to Microsoft.office.interop.oulook which can support Office 2021.

catch (Exception ex) return false <-- Don't do this, because it means you won't get any error details...

It isn't necessary to set your locals to = null in your finally. It's a cargo-cult practice carried-over from 1990s VBA programs and it wasn't necessary back then either (VBA handled COM object ref-counting for you just fine, and C# does it today).

You say you're getting the error _"Unable to cast COM object of type ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass’ to interface type ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application’." - but I don't see how you could get that from the oMsg.Send() call. What is the actual stack-trace of the exception?

Pretty sure what you want it just to use a normal Mailmessage with Outlook as outgoing mailserver. you don't want to use interop for this.

@ThomasKoelle Outlook isn't an "outgoing mailserver" - it isn't a mailserver at all...
